# Subclass explicit argument's typing using mypy

Tags: python, oop, mypy

I have the following:

```py
class Parent:
    def method(self, arg1: str, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        print("Hello", arg1)

class Child(Parent):
    def method(self, arg1: str, arg2: int, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        print("Hello", arg1, str(arg2))
```

The goal of this design is to force every subclasses of `Parent` to have an `arg1` argument, but to be free to add any argument after that. These following arguments are represented as `*args` and `**kwargs` in the `Parent`, and the `Child` "requires" `arg2`.

I know this is bad since `Child.method` should be able to be used anywhere where `Parent.method` is expected but the additional argument forbids that. However, is there a more gracious solution than replacing `*args` and `**kwargs` by some sort of `options: Dict[str, Any]` parameter in `Parent` and `Children` ?

I've heard about the Liskov Substitution Principle but don't know how to apply it in this case.